# How to add custom attribute (manufacturer) to product name in My Account - My Product Reviews

Tags: attributes, review, ce-1.9.2.2

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

This code works fine to display the manufacturer name is other places such as a product page, but not for adding the manufacturer name to the product name in the My Review section of the customer account.

Please share how to accomplish showing the custom attribute in app\design\frontend\mytheme\custom\template\review\customer\list.phtml

Comment: I don't understand your question Product attribute only for product . just Add before this <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?> then it will work

Comment: You might have to load the product first. Sometimes shell models are used which don't contain all the attributes

Comment: Kothari - Your suggestion produced the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /home/dev1921/public_html/app/design/frontend/intenso/custom/template/review/customer/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Unlike adding a custom attribute to product pages using code like `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>`, adding a custom attribute to the Customer Product Reviews detail page requires a slightly different format.

Add this to display your custom attribute such as manufacturer.

`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductData()->getAttributeText('custom_attribute')) ?>`